# Two Plots in One Figure using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot two plots in one figure: a histogram and a line plot based on the same x axis  tick labels from the histogram.

The histogram is just the frequency by `state` and `group`.

The line plot is the `target` by `state`.

I want the legends to be in the same box even though there are two axes (`ax1`, `ax2`).

I tried this but it doesn't work:

This works but there are two separate legend boxes:

```
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(h2, l2)
```

This only displays the `target` label:

```
h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)
```

Here is the full code:

```
data = {
    'state': ['nj', 'nj', 'nj', 'ny', 'ny', 'ny'],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'target': [20, 21, 19, 18, 15, 33]
}
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_test1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.histplot(
    data=df_test1,
    x='state', 
    hue='group',
    hue_order=['A', 'B'], 
    multiple='dodge',
    ax=ax, 
    shrink=.5,
    )

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(
    data=df_test1,
    x='state',
    y='target', 
    label='target',
    ax=ax2,
    )

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)
```

Comment: You could try `h1 = ax.legend_.legend_handles; l1 = [t.get_text() for t in ax.legend_.texts]`

Comment: This works thanks! but it makes a duplicate legend. Do you know how to just keep the one that has all?

Comment: You are problably referring to the legend of `ax2`. You can remove it with `ax2.legend_.remove()`.  (The old legend of `ax` is automatically removed when a new legend is created on the same `ax`.)